# After change SessionID data in Session variables is lost

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, sessionid

I have asp.net webforms application/ And what i need to do is to change ASP.NET_SessionId when user logs in.

When user logs in I execute the following code:

```
SessionIDManager Manager = new SessionIDManager();
string NewID = Manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
bool redirected = false;
bool IsAdded = false;
Manager.SaveSessionID(Context, NewID, out redirected, out IsAdded);
```

So, SessionId is changing after that.

But, then after that if I write some session variables, for example

```
Session["username"] = username;
```

then after postback our data is lost or associated with old session id.
and we have

```
Session["username"] == null
```

Please can you help me how to write to session variable after changing SessionId so that data will not be lost?

Comment: Do you let the client know you changed its sessions ID? Think there needs some cookie to be set.

Comment: Do you meen someting like this? Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = NewID; I did it, but it did not help.

Answer (score 5):

Command "Manager.SaveSessionID" will remove all data of old sessionid.
There is only one way to keep data. It's manual move data. You use the function below into login button:

```
...
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Reflection;

protected void ReGenerateSessionId()
    {
        SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
        string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(Context);
        string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
        bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;
        manager.RemoveSessionID(Context);
        manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newId, out isRedir, out isAdd);

        HttpApplication ctx = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
        HttpModuleCollection mods = ctx.Modules;
        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule ssm = (SessionStateModule)mods.Get("Session");
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = ssm.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        SessionStateStoreProviderBase store = null;
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo rqIdField = null, rqLockIdField = null, rqStateNotFoundField = null;

        SessionStateStoreData rqItem = null;
        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            if (field.Name.Equals("_store")) store = (SessionStateStoreProviderBase)field.GetValue(ssm);
            if (field.Name.Equals("_rqId")) rqIdField = field;
            if (field.Name.Equals("_rqLockId")) rqLockIdField = field;
            if (field.Name.Equals("_rqSessionStateNotFound")) rqStateNotFoundField = field;

            if ((field.Name.Equals("_rqItem")))
            {
                rqItem = (SessionStateStoreData)field.GetValue(ssm);
            }
        }
        object lockId = rqLockIdField.GetValue(ssm);

        if ((lockId != null) && (oldId != null))
        {
            store.RemoveItem(Context, oldId, lockId, rqItem);
        }

        rqStateNotFoundField.SetValue(ssm, true);
        rqIdField.SetValue(ssm, newId);
    }

protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (/*Login success*/)
    {
        ReGenerateSessionId(); // Change SessionID
        Session["User"] = user;
        Response.Redirect("Login_Success.aspx", true);
    }
}
```